# std::getline() returning memory address when using cout

Tags: c++, c++11

When the cout statement executes it returns a memory address.

```
string data = "Test String ";
string info;
ofstream file("data.dat", ios::binary);
ifstream fileI("data.dat", ios::binary);
file << data;
file.close();
cout << getline(fileI, data); // returns a memory address
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Note that `getline` as used here looks for a newline character. A binary file doesn't traffic in newlines. Use text files for text-oriented I/O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getline` function itself returns the input stream from the given first argument (`fileI` in your code). The result is saved in the 2rd argument (`data` in your code). So you need to run `getline(fileI, data)`first and then output the string `data`.

```
string data = "Test String ";
string info;
ofstream file("data.dat", ios::binary);
ifstream fileI("data.dat", ios::binary);
file << data;
file.close();
getline(fileI, data);
cout << data;
return 0;
```

Also see the [documentation of `getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

Answer (score 1):

std::getline returns a reference to the input stream. A stream cannot be sent to another stream directly, but it can be converted to a void pointer (until c++11).